# Does importing actually include a module?

Tags: elm, modularity

If I get a module called `A` which imports `B` and `C` :

```
module A exposing (..)

import B
import C
```

and `B` also imports `C` :

```
module B exposing (..)

import C
```

What will happen? Does `import` actually include `B` and `C` code, then `C` would appear twice inside `A` at compilation? Or does the compiler replace each occurrence of an imported module's member in `A` or `B` by its origin code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of how many modules another modules is referenced in, it only ever gets compiled once.

Here's an example that takes three files:

**A.elm**

```elm
module A exposing (..)

import B
import C

a : String
a =
    "Hi from A!\n" ++ B.b ++ "\n" ++ C.c
```

**B.elm**

```elm
module B exposing (..)

import C

b : String
b =
    "Hi from B!\n" ++ C.c
```

**C.elm**

```elm
module C exposing (..)

c : String
c =
    "Hi from C!"
```

The resulting transpiled javascript looks like this (your generated js may be different):

```js
var _user$project$C$c = 'Hi from C!';

var _user$project$B$b = A2(_elm_lang$core$Basics_ops['++'], 'Hi from B!\n', _user$project$C$c);

var _user$project$A$a = A2(
    _elm_lang$core$Basics_ops['++'],
    'Hi from A!\n',
    A2(
        _elm_lang$core$Basics_ops['++'],
        _user$project$B$b,
        A2(_elm_lang$core$Basics_ops['++'], '\n', _user$project$C$c)));
```

As you can see, the `C.elm` code was only included once.

Comment: So there is no problem with recursive imports either?

Comment: Import cycles are not allowed, if you were to try referencing A from B _and_ B from A. That would give you a compile error.